# How to fix 1 Socket in /run/screen/S-Ubuntu, not able to attach to any screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen

When I type screen -ls it shows following:

There is a screen on:

```
    28388.pts-0.ip-XXX-XX-XX-X      (03/07/19 18:45:54)     (Detached)
```

1 Socket in /run/screen/S-ubuntu.

I tried doing screen -r 28388, the screen shows attached but I come back to

the prompt and cannot run my program.

I see this

screen -r 28388
There is a screen on:

```
    28388.pts-0.ip-XXX-XX-XX-X      (03/07/19 18:45:54)     (Attached)
```

There is no screen to be resumed matching 28388.

ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-X:~/foldername$ screen -d 28388

[28388.pts-0.ip-XXX-XX-XX-X detached.]

ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-X:~/foldername$ screen -ls

There is a screen on:

```
    28388.pts-0.ip-XXX-XX-XX-X      (03/07/19 18:45:54)     (Attached)
```

1 Socket in /run/screen/S-ubuntu.

ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-X:~/foldername$

I want to attach to this screen and run my program. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It says you are already Attached, maybe you have another window inside your actual screen.

Try to do

```
[Ctrl+a] then hit SPACE BAR
```